# How do I play Whispers of Oblivion now that Legacy of the Void has launched?

Tags: starcraft-2

I only own Wings of Liberty. Is there a way for me to play the Whispers of Oblivion missions?

Answer (score 6):

The 'Whispers of Oblivion' beta early-access missions are now accessible as the prologue to the main Legacy of the Void campaign. i.e. You will have to purchase Legacy of the Void if you wish to play them:

Upon clicking on the 'Campaign' button you will be taken to the screen to select your campaign:

[image: Campaign selection screen]

When you go into the Protoss campaign, you will have the option of playing the Whispers of Oblivion Prologue missions:

[image: Chapter selection screen]

Comment: I am currently at work and unable to screenshot the relevant campaign screen, I will add it when I get home. Othewise If someone else feels like adding this for me, it'd be very much appreciated :)

Comment: How about these?